# Why can't I implement (inject) an interface into my ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm very new to working with large projects and dependencies, but I am moving an interface located within a Fragment into its own file to not be reliant on the Fragment that originally housed it.

The interface `MarkerInteractionListener` looks like

```
interface MarkerInteractionListener {
    fun currentLocation(): Location?
    ...
}
```

My MainActivity implements this interface by simply:

```
class MainActivity : MarkerInteractionListener, ... {

    override fun currentLocation(): Loction? = getLastKnownLocation()
    ...
}
```

When implementing the InteractionListener back into its original fragment, that is being done as:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment {
    
    private var interactionListener: MarkerInteractionListener? = null
    
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        if (context is MarkerInteractionListener) {
            interactionListener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("$context must implement MarkerInteractionListener")
        }
    }
    
    // I can now call interactionListener?.currentLocation()
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to get that interface into a ViewModel that will be utilizing the functions within the interface.
I've tried injecting it with the VM constructor

```
@HiltViewModel
class PointCreationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val interactionListener: MarkerInteractionListener,
    ...
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
    // I want to be able to call interactionListener.currentLocation()
}
```

This simply gets me the error message

```
MarkerInteractionListener cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

What am I missing within my interface or my ViewModel that doesn't allow me to Inject the interface for use? Can this even be injected? Is there another way?

Comment: Activities have a shorter lifetime than a ViewModel (which survives configuration changes like rotating your device where the activity itself would be destroyed and recreated). Injecting your activity would be a leak after a configuration change, wouldn't it?

Comment: Didn't realize that, but I would imagine so. Could there be an alternative way to reference the Interface from within the ViewModel? Alternatively, there is no direct Fragment for `PointCreationViewModel` as it really just stores the logic of a couple functions. Could a Repo/Impl pair implement the Interface? Seeing as a VM would likely introduce a leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PointCreationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val interactionListener: MarkerInteractionListener) : ViewModel(),
 MarkerInteractionListener by interactionListener {
  
}
```

and use the provide annotation in the interactionListenerImpl

Answer (score 0):

You must provide `MarkerInteractionListener` in AppModule

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).